# How to find the analytical formula f [x] of a function?

Tags: functions

The known conditions are:

```
f[2 x + 1 _] = x^2 - 2 x
```

How to find the analytical formula f [x] of this function?

Comment: `RSolve[f[2 x + 1 ] == x^2 - 2 x, f[x], x]` ?

Comment: Or by algebraic manipulation: `Simplify /@ (f[2 x + 1] == x^2 - 2 x /. Solve[y == 2 x + 1, x][[1]]) /. {y -> x, Equal -> Rule}`

Answer (score 4):

Obtain answers based on  Mariusz Iwaniuk prompts from netizens

```
RSolve[{f[2 x + 1] == x^2 - 2 x}, f[x], x] // Simplify // Expand
```